# How can I run Chef Install from a C# application

Tags: chef-infra, azure-service-fabric, chefdk

I am trying to figure out a way to run Chef Install to generate Chef policy files in my C# Azure Service Fabric Application. Unfortunately I not having much luck finding information to support this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start`, just like any other external process spawning in C#.